# Is it a good practice to store DTO object in SQL table as bytes

Tags: java, sql, object, dto

I have a DTO object which can have multiple lists of other DTO objects. I want to persist this DTO object so that it can be reused later. Can we store the DTO object in the DB? Is it a good practice?
What if the size of the DTO object increases.
We are using SQL Server as the database server.

Comment: Storing serialized Java objects as a "blob"  in the database is a really, really bad idea. You will have tons of problem in the long run.

Comment: if small.. sometimes people store JSONs as CLOBs
Technically its not a great practice but sometimes such solutions work best for the problem at hand

Comment: If storing objects in the "blob" column is not recommended, should I create entities and tables for each DTO object to store the data??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use JSON rather than bytes to store an object. The data type for the column could be VARCHAR(MAX). This has an advantage in terms of readability as well as being easy to parse JSON back to your object in many coding languages. However, you mention the DTO object having lists of other DTO objects and being used later. Why not make entities in the database? It depends on your use case.